# transfer video without compressiing

Tags: gstreamer

I am using gstreamer for streaming a video. The server side is 
`gst-launch v4l2src ! jpegenc ! udpsink host=<ip> port=5000` 
and for the client side
`gst-launch udpsrc port=5000 ! jpegdec ! xvimagesink`.
This one is working pretty good.

My requirement is : I would like to transfer the video without using a compression technique like jpegenc. would like to connect v4l2src directly to udpsink. when I tried such a connection, errors were not generated. but video is not getting transfered.

Answer (score -1):

udp is not a lossless protocol.  Chances are your video buffers are going to be too big to handle properly.

Why not try with tcpserversink and tcpclientsrc instead ?